# Как лучше выделять память для динамического массива?

Tags: массивы, delphi

Здравствуйте, уважаемые знатоки. Собственно вопрос:
Как лучше выделять память для динамического массива - `SetLength` или `AllocMem`?
Например:

```
type
  TMyArray = array of Integer;
var
  MyArray: TMyArray;
  PMyArray: ^TMyarray;
begin
//Вариант с SetLength
SetLength(MyArray,High(Word));
.....какие-нибудь действия.....
//Вариант с AllocMem
try
  PMyArray := AllocMem(High(Word)*SizeOf(Word));
  .................
  какие-нибудь действия
  .................
finaly
  FreeMem(PMyArray,High(Word)*SizeOf(Word));
end;
```

Или без разницы?

Answer (score 7):

Если Вам нужно для внутреннего использования, то однозначно `SetLength`. Так как автоматом получаете контроль выхода за пределы массива, типизацию, автоматическое освобождение, простое увеличение размера и прочие плюшки.

В варианте с `AllocMem` нужно все делать ручками. Даст ли выигрыш в скорости? сильно сомневаюсь. думаю, что `SetLength` внутри использует `AllocMem`.

Comment: Один важный момент, если память выделена с пом. SetLength то при попытке добавить к массиву несколько записей(увеличить его длинну) ваш массив будет перемещен в новое место в памяти без данных которые он содержал, пару раз накололся на таком..

Comment: Сильно сомневаюсь. Вот такой пример

    var a:array of integer;
    begin
      SetLength(a,3);
      a[2] := 10;
      SetLength(a,10000);
      ShowMessage(inttostr(a[2]));
    end;

выведет 10. Отлично работает.

Comment: Возможно, в таком массиве Вы хранили объекты. Вот здесь могут быть всякие особенности.  Например, при уменьшении размера не будут автоматически вызываться деструкторы. Но для объектов лучше использовать TList и TCollection (или их наследников).

Comment: В массиве действительно были ссылки на классы(обьекты), но проблема возникала именно при увеличении массива.

    var a:array of pointer;
    I:integer;
    begin
      for i:=0 to 1000 do
      begin  
        SetLength(a,length(a)+2);
        a[max(a)] := TStringList.create;
        TStringList(a[max(a)]).text='SomeText';
      end;
      //еще проход по массиву, часть элементов массива будет пуста, опустошение произойдет когда невозможно в том же месте где находится массив получить еще место под новые элементы - справка по делфи и личный опыт.
    end;

Comment: данный неприятный момент нормальным образом так и не нашел как обойти, пришлось использовать двунаправленые списки(хотя там изначально их и надо было использовать..)

Comment: конечно, часть элементов будут пустые - Вы добавляете два элемента к массиву, а заполняете последний (хотя я не уверен, что именно возвращает max).

Comment: Прошу прощенья в коде ошибка там должно быть не Length(a)+2 а max(a)+2 или length(a)+1; пример набран был по памяти и допустил упущение, но это не отменяет того что описано в коментарии) именно подряд значений массива от начала до N не будет, N - последнее перемещение в памяти массива. делфи не следит за тем что было в записях, не хватает места старое освобождается, новое(в новом месте памяти) создается. к сожалению это так, и описано в документацие. т.е. перед увеличением длинны нужно самим позаботится переносом старых значений массива.

Comment: Зы. и 

     Возможно, в таком массиве Вы хранили объекты. Вот здесь могут быть всякие особенности. Например, при уменьшении размера не будут автоматически вызываться деструкторы. 

Я не про утечку памяти, а про физическое отсутствие того что я в массив клал) тобиш ссылок на класы.

Comment: Давайте так, соберите рабочий пример, который воспроизводит проблему, опубликуйте как вопрос (а может быть и как исследование) и я (и, надеюсь, другие люди с хэшкода) проанализирую код, посмотрю что там.

Comment: > Existing characters in the string or elements in the array are preserved, but the content of newly allocated space is undefined.

все будет хорошо. [скорее всего] ошибка в коде.

Answer (score 0):

```
SetLength(a,length(a)+2);
```

Так ведь это потому что вы пустые элементы в этот массив запихиваете. Конечно, они там будут.